# Ruby Injection of factorial

Tags: ruby, math

```
(1..40).inject(:*) / (2*(1..20).inject(:*))
```

I should get the answer `137846528820` instead of `167683548393178540705382400000`

Could someone help me why my number is extremely large?
I was looking for C(40,20)

Answer (score 3):

The formula is incorrect, you are using `40! / 2 * 20!`, whle it should be `40! / (20! * 20!)`.

```
(1..40).inject(:*) / ((1..20).inject(:*) ** 2)
# => 137846528820
```

Comment: Correct. For thoroughness, the complete formula for `C(40,20)` = `n! / ((n-k)! * k!)` = `40! / ((40-20)! * 20! )` = `40! / (20! * 20!)`